# Is it acceptable to use an event aggregator to communicate between model classes in WPF MVVM application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model, eventaggregator

I am unsure what a good/proper way is to communicate between model classes in a WPF MVVM application. Right now, my model classes use an event aggregator (Caliburn.Micro specifically) to communicate with other model classes.

I'm not sure if this is considered an anti-pattern or not but something doesn't feel right (see **note** below). I like the loose coupling the event aggregator provides but I could imagine the abstraction making the code potentially more difficult to read. But then again, that also seems like a consequence of abstraction.

**Note**: At this time the same event aggregator is being used for model->model class communication and viewmodel<->model class communication. I could see this being not desirable and if the answer to my question is yes, I could easily create a separate event aggregator that is dedicated to model<->model class communication.

I understand the usefulness of an event aggregator, particularly for viewmodel<->viewmodel communication and viewmodel<->model communication. But, the application under discussion has a fairly complex model and I am unsure if using an event aggregator is an appropriate choice for model<->model communication.

Is it acceptable to use an event aggregator to communicate between model classes in WPF MVVM application?

If yes, should I use 2 event aggregators in my application?

- One for viewmodel<->viewmodel & viewmodel<->model class communcation.
- One for model<->model class communication.

If no, what alternative would you suggest?

Thanks!

**Edit:** It's been a little over 2 months since I asked this. Over this time I have done some significant re-architecting & refactoring of my application. In this process I have managed to eliminate 99% of the event aggregator usage in my application. I ended up finding most of my usages of the event aggregator *unnecessary* (I had a s*** ton). I was able to eliminate event aggregator messages by organizing my application better and I also replaced some of the messages with observables (an excellent alternative IMO). So, if anyone sees this is going down the route of relying on an event aggregator heavily, take a step back and think about what you are doing cause there is likely a better way to do it!

Comment: For VM <-> VM, it is the preferred method. Why would a model need to talk to another model or to a VM? That sounds like you aren't doing something right to me. Models should strictly deal with themselves.

Comment: @SledgeHammer I don't see how this is true. It is my understanding that the model contains data and application logic. If I have a class (in the model) that reads data from a serial port, I would tend to have a separate class (in the model) to do the processing of that data.

Comment: Nope :). "The key to remember with the model is that it holds the information, but not behaviors or services that manipulate the information.". With a database app, the model would be the EF POCOs for example. There's no logic in them. You would have a DAL for that. In your example, the model would be the data representation of what you pull off the serial port. The serial port reading / writing definitely doesn't go in the model. Since they are data holders, there is no communication with anybody unless they implement INPC.

Comment: @SledgeHammer In what area of an MVVM application do you think serial port reading/writing should go?

Comment: In a DAL. Same difference as database reading / writing. You have a DAL that populates the model POCOs. POCOs don't do anything on their own.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there are several approaches you can use to communicate between classes, but I think this is a fairly easy **Yes, its fine**.

Your event aggregator is basically a message bus, there's nothing wrong with using that concept for communicating within an application. The fact that some things are view models and others models isn't really relevant. For that reason, I would think one would suffice.

That being said, numerous events may not be the best option (due to type explosion or magic strings, depending on your framework, if nothing else). If you can, I would direct messages at a specific interface (perhaps make that, or something based on that the event type) and method name, and build helper classes to parse the messages and use reflection to call the appropriate code. This approach has worked very well for me in the past (though it takes a fair bit of effort to build the helper classes).

An alternative to consider would be using a dependency injection container for all your model classes, so they simply depend on the things they are trying to talk to. The main downside to this is getting a DI container integrated well into WPF can be... difficult.

Comment: Magic strings? In an event aggregator? Where? Every event aggregator I've ever seen uses strongly typed messages.

Comment: @SledgeHammer I'm pretty sure MVVMLight's uses strings, but I'm happy to take that section out